# There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace. When installing API Authentication In laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting below error when i run 
  **php artisan passport:install**

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace.
```

Answer (score 36):

For installing laravel passport make sure you add this line to **config/app.php** in the providers array (package service providers section):

```
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

Then install the package and migrate the database

```
composer require laravel/passport
php artisan migrate 
php artisan passport:install
```

Clearing out the cache is generally helpful first step when commands are not working, especially when you update anything in the **config** folder on .env files.

```
php artisan config:clear  
php artisan config:cache
```

Config clear removes the configuration cache file. Config cache creates a new configuration cache file with the current settings. Config cache enables faster load times for your apps!

Comment: that answer works for me, i think it is the right answer.

Comment: This answer gives the best procedure. Worked for me.

Comment: When I put `composer require laravel/passport` I obtain `Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.48
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
- laravel/passport v8.4.1 requires illuminate/http ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/`   How Can I install Passport?

Answer (score 6):

I got solution. After running following two commands every thing work fine.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cach
```

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a solution for this and I found simple one that worked for me:

Add these lines to `$commands` array in `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```php
    \Laravel\Passport\Console\InstallCommand::class,
    \Laravel\Passport\Console\KeysCommand::class,
    \Laravel\Passport\Console\ClientCommand::class,
```

Answer (score 2):

Just follow these steps:

1. composer require laravel/passport.
   Once the installation finishes, add the following provider in the config/app.php file: Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
2. php artisan migrate
3. php artisan passport:install

Comment: Steps 1, 3 and 4 worked for me to get it up, but not sure what step 2 requires?

Comment: Basically you add the line of code in step 2  in your config/app.php file as part of the items in the providers array.

Comment: I got it now. It was in another answer. I went through your answer first! Think that step should be made clearer. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Try running `composer require laravel/passport "~9.0"` before running `php artisan passport:install`

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the solution of install Laravel passport with mongodb:

Just replace the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` with `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model` in below files:

```
..\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Token.php,
..\vendor\laravel\passport\src\AuthCode.php
..\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Client.php
..\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessClient.php
```

and `protected $table= "Table_name"` variable with `protected $collection="Table_name"`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you explain why your answer is valid and not just provide the code.