# Calling passport:client from route, "there are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

I have an issue where the `passport` namespace is not available when I call `passport:client`. I set up a brand new Laravel project with version 5.6.34 where I installed [Laravel passport according to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#installation). I also checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45121048/1260548) and followed all steps there with no sucess.

Calling `php artisan passport:client --password --name="Test"` from the command line works without any issues and I can see the client in the database.

However if I create a route in `routes/web.php` like so:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/', function () {
    Artisan::call('passport:client', [
        '--password' => true,
        '--name' => "Test client",
        '--quiet' => true,
    ]);
});
```

and use the Artisan facade to call the command I get the error below when I navigate to `http://homestead.test/`.

`Symfony \ Component \ Console \ Exception \ CommandNotFoundException
The command "passport:client" does not exist.`

I have added `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class` in the providers array in `config/app.php`.

**How can I call the `passport:client` command from a web route?**

We have a Laravel application that has several hundred database connections which are handled dynamically. In the admin interface you can create a new project and thus a new database where we need to generate a client.

My other option is the instantiate a `ClientRepository` and call the `createPasswordGrantClient()` method but I would like to avoid this if possible. I am curious to know why the namespace is available when called on the CLI but not via a request. I can call other commands such as `migrate:fresh` via a request but `passport:client` will fail even if it is part of the migration or inside another command.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/197), I ran the below commands.

```
composer update

php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install
```

This helped me.

Comment: Thanks but this is the same as my linked similar question that did not help, I appreciate the time you took to look into this however. Maybe it will help someone else with a similar issue